# How to set permission to Control in WebPart in this scenario?

Tags: development, web-part, permissions, groups

I am having the Visual Webpart in VS2012 for SharePoint2010 site. On this webpart  there is `Publish` button. I want to make visible and enabled to HR Group.What Permission I need to set for HR Group and for other users? Other user should not even see that button. What I have to do for this ?

I used following :

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl1" PermissionsString="BrowseDirectories" runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly">
    <asp:Button ID="btnPublish" runat="server" Text="Publish Top 10" OnClick="btnPublish_Click" />
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

But all users able to see this button on Webpart after deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by code also:

```
if (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(g => g.Name == "hr Group"))
 {
    show button
 }
 else
 {
    hide button
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`SPGroup.ContainsCurrentUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.containscurrentuser.aspx) is also an option.

You can get the HR group as usual and check if the HR group contains the current user. Then, it's just about hide/disable that button.